# Positioning Infobox without map pan

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

On click event JavaScript draws my InfoBox window and then auto adjust it position on map. While auto adjustment the map pans to some level I don't want to do it ! If I place marker on right corner infobox should open on left and if i place marker on left corner of map infobox should open on right side of map and same should happen for top and bottom of map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<style>
    .infobox-wrapper {
    display:none;
}
#infobox {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #60AEA7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 56px;
    left: 19%;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
   margin-top: -107px;
    width: 214px;
    z-index: -9;
}
#infobox h3{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #06A79E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#infobox p{
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: -13px; 
}

#infobox img{
 margin-left: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var loc, map, marker, infobox;

    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.89542, 151.274856);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
         zoom: 12,
         center: loc,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: loc,
        visible: true
    });
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
var mm=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

mm.setMap(map)
    infobox = new InfoBox({
         content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
         disableAutoPan: false,
         maxWidth: 150,
         pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
         zIndex: null,
         boxStyle: {
           width: "280px"
        },
        closeBoxMargin: "-105px 16px 2px 0",

        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
    });
    // $('.place_name').html("hi")
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            $(".place_name").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
        infobox.open(map, this);

    });   
    google.maps.event.addListener(mm, 'mouseover', function() {
        infobox.open(map, this);

    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<title>Creating and Using an InfoBox</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
<br>


<div class="infobox-wrapper">
    <div id="infobox">
         <h3>Place Name : <span class="place_name">State Bank of India</span></h3>
            <p>Distance From Center : <span id="kmTxt">14 KM</span></p>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvjvignesh/jEhJ3/2477/)

Comment: Welcome on SO! Could you expand your question a bit, explaining more clearly what the problem is and, if possible companied by a jsfiddle? Please also only post relevant code, with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEhJ3/2479/)**

What you have to do first, is calculate in which quarter of the screen the marker is positioned. This can be done quite easily: get the center of the map (`map.getCenter()`), the position of the marker (`marker.getPosition()`) and subtract long and lat values. If the center of the map is further left, the marker is positioned on the right and vice versa.

Now if you know on which side the marker is, you can easily position the infobox. If the marker is on the right side, offset the infobox more to the left, and vice versa (same applies to top and left).

Check out the fiddle for an example. It works, but you should alter the pointer position yourself.

Comment: Thanks it works ! Wht does mapCenter.d , markerPosition.d ,mapCenter.e,markerPosition.e indicates ?

Comment: those are the Long/Lat values. Checkout [the manual](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)